# Why this line doesn't work user.Age = (result[11] == string.Empty) ? (int?) null : Int32.Parse(result[11])

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, code-snippets, ternary-operator

Assume `result[11] == string.Empty` (i.e. `result[11] = ""`)

```
if (result[11] == string.Empty) // this block works fine
{
    user.Age = Int32.Parse(result[11]);
}
else
{
    user.Age = null;
}

// the following line will throw exception
user.Age = (result[11] == string.Empty) ? (int?) null : 
                                          Int32.Parse(result[11]);
```

> > System.FormatException was unhandled
> >       Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
> >       Source=mscorlib
> >       StackTrace:
> >            at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, >> >> NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
> >            at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
> >            at System.Int32.Parse(String s)

To me, the above two blocks are same. Then why the first one works while the second one doesn't?

Comment: Are you sure the first line isn't supposed to be if(result[11] != string.Empty) ?

Comment: you should prefer string.IsNullOrEmpty( ) instead of mystring == string.Empty

Comment: The error is right in the exception message: you're parsing something that's not parseable.  Perhaps the value is null, or a non-numeric string?

Comment: They don't look the same. The actions are backwards

Comment: Assuming the first line is supposed to be != not ==, if string[11] is null, not empty, you cannot parse null to int, so like Maud'Dib said, use .IsNullOrEmpty()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The blocks are not the same.

```
if (result[11] == string.Empty) // this block works fine
{
    user.Age = Int32.Parse(result[11]);
}
```

That block should actually not work, because the block will only parse an empty string.  Switch the code in the "if" block and the "else" block, and it will be identical to your ternary "? :" operator.

Comment: ...at which point neither will work, since he's clearly trying to parse an invalid string!

Comment: @James Johnston, fair enough that logic is not right but the exception he is getting is caused but the fact that he's trying to parse and invalid string as integer. I think the result[11] == string.Empty was meant to be !=

Answer (score 1):

The result that you are trying to parse as Integer is not a valid Integer, hence the exceptions.
Rather do the following.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result[11]))
{
    if (!Int32.TryParse(result[11], out user.Age))
        user.Age = null; // not really needed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this:

```
        var value = "";
        int? age;

        if (value != string.Empty)
        {
            age = Int32.Parse(value);
        }
        else
        {
            age = null;
        }


        age = (value == string.Empty) ? (int?)null : Int32.Parse(value);
```

and it works fine (I have changed the `==` to `!=` in the first if).

Answer (score 1):

Everyone answered how you are trying to parse invalid strings as integer. They are right. However, apparently people have missed that your code is not equivalent, because you have inverted the ternary clauses. This would be your equivalent code:

```
//if this is your code:
if (result[11] == string.Empty) // this block works fine
{
    user.Age = Int32.Parse(result[11]);
}
else
{
    user.Age = null;
}

//This is your equivalent ternary. You have inverted here
user.Age = (result[11] == string.Empty) ? Int32.Parse(result[11]) : 
                                          null;
```

Answer (score 0):

result[i] might return 'object', ergo  cast:

```
     (string) result[i] == ....
     Int.Parse(  (string) result[i] )
```

Comment: or use ToString(), cast COULD fail (but, maybe you want it to)

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. Int32.Parse() requires a string parameter. If result[] was an object array, the code wouldn't even compile.